# Low Variables and Matrix and Playa - Oh My!

Tags: matrix, playa, low-variables

I've been searching everywhere and tried many options, so I'm reaching our for some help.

I'm Running EE 2.6.1, LV 2.4.2, Matrix 2.5.10 and Playa 4.4.5.

I've got a Low Variable called 'lv_obv_lot_directory' with 2 columns:  one is a simple dropdown (with numbers) called 'm_lot_location' and the other is a Playa field called 'm_lot_vendor', which pulls from a channel called obv_members.

Running this in the basic form

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="lv_obv_lot_directory"}
  <div>{m_lot_location}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

gets me a list of the numbers (in the order they are listed in the LV).

But I can't get it to pull the list of associated vendors.  I've tried so many things, including a special embedded template.  The closest I came was with an embedded template

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="obv_members" fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}"  dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories" status="not closed"} which just gave me a list of all of the vendor entries.  If I change it to fixed_order="0|{embed:entry_ids}" then I just get the first entry.
```

I think I'm close, but obviously missing something.  HELP!!!  :(

Comment: What's the exact string you're feeding into the fixed_order parameter?

Comment: If you rephrase your comment as an answer, I'll give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob's post had me rethink the embed tag that I had, and in doing so I realized that there was an error in what was being fed to the fixed_order parameter.  Once I fixed this, things started to populate as expected.